# How to generate a compile_commands.json file for OpenBSD Make

Tags: c++, c, makefile, openbsd

I recently installed OpenBSD and cloned the source code to my machine. I use vim+coc+clangd as an autocomplete for c&c++. I used to use [compiledb](https://pypi.org/project/compiledb/) for generating the compile_commands.json file but turns out it doesn't work with OpenBSD make.
I would like to be able to generate a compile_commands.json file for the OpenBSD sourcehy compiledb does not work on OpenBSD make code.
what I tried to do:
I tried to use gmake instead of make but the OpenBSD source code needs OpenBSD make to compile.
Thanks!
Update

###### Update Response to [the busybee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11294831/the-busybee)

the reason why compiledb does not work on OpenBSD make is because it relies on the -w flag which is not an OpenBSD make flag.

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like a log to look into for error messages? _Why_ does compiledb refrain to work with OpenBSD make?

Comment: This question is better off as a feature request on compiledb: https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb/issues